# Have two actioncables /cable web socket servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm getting some errors on my rails app that's doing a lot of cross domain stuff, and i'm trying to find a minor fix for this.

Is it possible to have multiple /cable url's inside the production file so that it uses both or whichever works?

example code:

```
  config.web_socket_server_url = ['wss://example.herokuapp.com/cable', 'wss://www.example.com']
```

i've tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using two heroku app, you can store the url of you app to a environment variable and reference that variable in you configuration. First in you terminal

```
heroku config:set -a YOUR_APP_NAME RAILS_HOST="YOUR_APP_URL"
```

then set the configuration

```
config.web_socket_server_url="wss://#{ENV['RAILS_HOST']}/cable"
```

If your second app is not a in-app case, then your should store complete url for both apps and use

```
config.web_socket_server_url=ENV['RAILS_HOST']
```